# Skipping first column update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've the below code that update the Spreadsheets data based on the posted input:
The code is checking if the header name is `Timestamp` then it enters the date, otherwise entered the field received in the posted data (based on index).
In the first column, i.e. `column A` I've the below formula: `={"Message Ref"; ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(B2:B)=0,,"MSG.Int."&if(row(A2:A)-1<10,"00"&row(A2:A)-1,if(row(A2:A)-1<100,"0"&row(A2:A)-1,row(A2:A)-1))))}` and I do not need the script to post any data on it.

```
function doPost(e) {
  // Prevent concurrent access overwritting data
  // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

  // As we are passing JSON in the body, we need to unpairs it
  var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
  e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  try {
    // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
  //  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(FILE_Id);
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    
    // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 
    // loop through the header columns
    for (i in headers){
      if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
        row.push(new Date());
      } else { // else use header name to get data
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
      }
    }
    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
    // return json success results
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid writing something on the first column, on the following lines :

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
...
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
```

replace the second parameter of `getRange` (`1`) by `2`